# TextInputEditText Hint remains in the background when the field value is set programmatically

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I determine the user's location and display it in a TextInputEditText field. The hint, however, remains in the background. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLayoutAutocomplete"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/standort"
            android:layout_weight="1">

 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
                android:inputType="text"
                />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

To set the value::

```
  binding.autocomplete.setText(place.toString())
  //Also not working:
  //binding.textLayoutAutocomplete.hint = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the text, you can set the `isHintEnabled` of `TextInputLayout` to `false`.

```
binding.textLayoutAutocomplete.isHintEnabled = false
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
binding.autocomplete.setText(place.toString());
binding.textLayoutAutocomplete.setHint(""); // Set hint to an empty string
```